# Textbox for DateTime wrong format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I know this is one of the most frequently asked questions.
I had the solution to this but my current project is driving me nuts.
I use the exact same code and still the result is different.

This is the code I normally use to format my dates:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Normally this should result in 07/10/2014 but for some reason it results in 07-10-2014
When I test it in another project the code above works as expected.

As a test I compared the results of the follow lines:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
/* result: 07-10-2014*/
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda)
/* result: 7-10-2014 00:00:00*/
```

So my code seems to work partially only the '-' won't be replaced by '/'
Does somebody know how to handle this once and for all?

### EDIT

I have custom code setting the Culture.
It uses the route to set it to a specific culture (default is 'nl')
When I put the code below in comments everything seems to work.
But I need this part to load my resources (label text, errors, ...).

```
var language = handler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["language"];

if (language != null)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language.ToString());
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language.ToString());
}
```

To be more specific this line breaks the format

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language.ToString());
```

Does anybody know why? I would expect that `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` has priority because it is explicitly set.
Funny part is that the `/` is just translated to `-`.
When I use `{0:dd//MM//yyyy}` it results in `19--10--2014`.

### EDIT

Sorry for my late response but I couldn't find the time to try this out.
So basically the problem was the culture and my format settings.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

The '/' still gets replaced by the divider specified by your culture.
My culture was set to 'nl' but by default this results in 'nl-nl' where they use '-' as date separator. I live in Belgium 'nl-be' and here we use '/'.
The could have set my culture or change the format.
The code below did the trick.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}")
```

Comment: Maybe somehow CultureInfo problem?

Comment: Cultureinfo is set in my global.asax depending on the route.
It is set to 'nl' at this moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with ASP.NET MVC, but if you don't specify a format, your current culture's `DateTimeFormat` is used. Also, `/` is a special format specifier in .NET which means "replace me with the current `DateTimeFormat`s date-separator which seems to be `-`.

So you should provide `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or mask the format specifier by using `\\/`instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}")
```

or by using the character literal `'/'`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}")
```

Read: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be by design. [TextBoxFor](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs) sets the value as per the following code snippet

```
string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
```

which calls the EvalString method of [HtmlHelper](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs)

```
internal string EvalString(string key, string format)
{
  return Convert.ToString(ViewData.Eval(key, format), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

which calls the Eval method of [ViewDataDictionary](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewDataDictionary.cs)

```
public string Eval(string expression, string format)
{
  object value = Eval(expression);
  return FormatValueInternal(value, format);
}

internal static string FormatValueInternal(object value, string format)
{
  ....
  return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, format, value);
}
```

So the value uses the format of the current culture. I presume this is because the `DefaultModelBinder` use the current culture info to parse the string representation of the date back to a `DateTime` (if you were able to override it, it would not bind unless you created a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0):

View Page

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfAgenda, new { Value = Model.DateOfAgenda.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")});
```

Comment: Count the parentheses and curly braces. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Hi krumia, that my mistake, miss one '}'..try again

Comment: Using @ value in the inside  parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Model page

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateOfAgenda{ get; set;}
```

View Page

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfAgenda)
```